# Iwasawa's Theorem for Simple Groups

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to work through a proof of Iwasawa's Theorem:

> Let $G$ act faithfully and primitively on a set $\Omega$. Let $\alpha\in\Omega$ and denote by $H$ the point stabiliser $G_{\alpha}$. Suppose further that
>
> - $H$ has an abelian normal subgroup $A$ such that $G=<A^g\mid g\in G >$;
> - G=[G,G], the derived subgroup of $G$.
>
> Then $G$ is simple.

The proof I'm working through is as follows:

Suppose that $K$ is a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$, $K\lhd G$. Then (as $G$ acts primitively) $K$ acts transitively on $\Omega$, and thus $G=KH$. But $AK$ is normalised by both $K$ and $H$, so $AK\lhd G$. But $G$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$, i.e. $AK=G$. Thus
\begin{equation}
G/K \cong (AK)/K\cong A/(A\cap K),
\end{equation}
so that $G/K$ is Abelian. Then $G=[G,G]\leq K$, i.e. $G=K$, whence $G$ is simple. $\qquad\square$

**My first question** is how to verify the (apparently trivial) claim that both $H$ and $K$ normalise $AK$. For the first, I understand that
\begin{equation}
(AK)^h = h^{-1}AKh=h^{-1}Ahh^{-1}Kh=A^h K^{h^{-1}}=AK,\ \forall h\in H
\end{equation}
since $A\lhd H$ and $K\lhd G$. For the second:
\begin{equation}
(AK)^k = k^{-1}AKk=k^{-1}Ak^{-1}Kh=A^k K,\ \forall k\in K.
\end{equation}
Do we know that $A\lhd K$? Why does $A^k=A$?

**My second question**: does the fact that $G$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ follow from the fact it is generated from the `$A^g$'s? If so, how exactly? If not, where does this condition come in?

**My final question** is: how we deduce that $G/K$ is Abelian from this string of isomorphisms? I know basic facts about normal subgroups and derived subgroups, but this goes over my head. This course, in general, kills me.

Any help with any of these three questions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope my proof can help for your questions. There are some typos in your statements, but I guess you may need this:

We have $KG_\alpha = G$ as what you did. For any $g\in G$, $g = kh$ for some $k\in K$ and $h\in G_\alpha$. Then
    \begin{equation*}
 gAg^{-1} = khAh^{-1}k^{-1} = kAk^{-1},
 \end{equation*}
    since $A\lhd G_\alpha$. (Here we may assume $A$ is contained in $G_\alpha$, for the stabilizers are all conjugate.) Since $K\lhd G$ we have $gAg^{-1} = kAk^{-1}\le KA$. Thus $\langle A^G\rangle\le KA$ and so $KA = G$. Hence
    \begin{equation*}
 G/K = KA/K\cong A/(A\cap K)
 \end{equation*}
    is abelian (since $A$ is abelian, and so does its quotient groups), and thus $G'\le K$, and we are done.

Comment: You mentioned some typos in my statement: could you point these out explicitly? They could be accidental or the reason things aren't clicking. One point I'll make is that we are working with right group actions not left, so $A^g=g^{-1}Ag$ by definition.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "$G$  is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$", and also $K$ is transitive, but not $H$.

Comment: You can change left group actions to right, the results will not change.

Comment: I think your question is just why $A^g\le KA$: this is because $K$ is normal, and $A^g = A^k$ for some $k$.

Comment: I'm looking over this with fresh eyes and I'm hoping you might be able to provide with me a little more clarification: I understand that you have shown that $A^k=A^g$ (though your order of quantification is not what I think I need: I'm sure we can switch things around to get this for all $k$ there exists $g$, rather than vice versa). I'm still unsure exactly what you have done to conclude that $k$ normalises $AK$. How have you used that stabilisers are conjugate? (I also realise that left vs right actions isn't important, for a moment I thought that was the perceived typo.)

Comment: $kAk^{-1} = \{kak^{-1}:a\in A\}$, and for any $a$, there exists $k_1\in K$ such that $ak^{-1} = k_1a$ since $K$ is normal. Hence $kak^{-1} = kk_1a\in KA$.@Ben

Comment: $K$ is an arbitrary normal subgroup of $G$, there exists some $\alpha$ such that $KG_\alpha = G$. Here $\alpha$ depends on $K$. But $A$ may be contained in $G_\beta$ for some $\beta$. It doesn't matter because we are considering conjugates of $A$. So I used the fact that all stabilizers are conjugate to assume $A\le G_\alpha$.

Comment: With this theorem can you prove that the alternating group $A_n$ is simple for $5≤n$?

Comment: @Tomais See this: https://mathoverflow.net/a/233215/131819.